# Proving that this is a complete metric space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I need to prove if we let $C[a,b]$ be the set of continuous functions on a closed interval $[a,b]$ and for $f,g \in C[a,b]$, define $\rho(f,g)=\displaystyle{\max_{t\in[a,b]}} |f(t)-g(t)|$. Show that $(C[a,b],\rho)$ is complete.

My first thought was that since we know that $[a,b]$ and $f[a,b]$ are both compact, we can just use compactness to show immediately that this is complete but I have a feeling that we can not do this. If we can not do this, I am leaning towards using the definition of continuity to show there are Cauchy sequences $f_n$ that converge in the set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Let $(f_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence. Then

- $(f_n(t))$ is a Cauchy sequence of real numbers for any $t\in [a,b],$ using continuity and compactness. Thus, $(f_n(t))$ is convergent for any $t.$ Call $f(t)$ the limit of such a sequence.
- Using continuity and compactnes again, show that $f$ is continuous and that $(f_n)\to f$ .

Is $f$ is continuous? Consider $x_0\in [a,b].$ Then,

$$\begin{array}{rcl}|f(x_0)-f(x)|&=&|f(x_0)-f_n(x_0)+f_n(x_0)-f_n(x)+f_n(x)-f(x)|\\&\le& |f(x_0)-f_n(x_0)|+|f_n(x_0)-f_n(x)|+|f_n(x)-f(x)|.\end{array}$$ Use that $(f_n(x_0))\to f(x_0),$ $(f_n(x))\to f(x)$ and $f_n$ is continuous.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You are right. I have forgotten to include this essential point. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I understand your first point, but not the second. How would we go by showing that it tends towards $f$? Would we want to show that So we must show that for every $\epsilon>0, \exists \thinspace \delta>0$ such that... My definition is wrong here I have edited it out.